# virt-install command missing after kvm installation

Tags: kvm

Installed Ubuntu (headless) Server 22.04.1, which I have been using without problem.

Following this tutorial, https://ubuntu.com/blog/kvm-hyphervisor, I installed kvm, which answers to `kvm-ok`, but I cannot find `virt-install` anywhere (`which virt-install`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I later discovered (looking for remote management options) that it turns out that the tutorial had things out of order. Before you can execute `virt-install`, you have to install *virt-manager*, a dependency and step not described in this tutorial nor was it mentioned. Here's how to do it:

```
# apt-get install virt-manager
# which virt-install
/usr/bin/virt-install
```

This tutorial may be successfully re-engaged at this point.

Comment: For future viewers, this page also h as that info https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/virt-install